# Where to put website files on hosting server?

Tags: webserver, website, web-hosting

I'm trying to publish a website I created but can't figure out where in the hosting server I should put my website files. The server folders looks like this:

[image]

I only added `index.html` and `.htaccess`. Even though `index.html` is present in the root directory, when I try to connect to my website it shows a server not found error. I tried to move the homepage to all the folders, but I still have the same issue. My `.htaccess` looks like this:
`DirectoryIndex index.html`. Changing it to `DirectoryIndex public_html/index.html` doesn't remove the problem. What am I doing wrong and where should I put my website files?

Comment: My guess would be the www folder.

Comment: "when I try to connect to my website it shows a **server not found** error" - It looks you have more problems than just folder placement.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy What other problem does it seems I have?

Comment: @DannySchoemann: Works as well, it is a symbolic link to the public_html directory.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Apparently it was a DNS problem, the hosting provider solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Public files go into the public folders; for your homepage, that is `public_html`.

Comment: I tried to put it into the `public_html` folder but nothing changes.

Comment: @moray95: Change the `.htaccess` back to `DirectoryIndex index.html`